# Configure SQL server to store UTC date Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

Is There some way to configure sql server to store UTC time in the database if passed local date time values??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You need to either convert to UTC before passing to SQL Server or after.

A `DateTime` instance that is passed in to SQL Server looses the associated `DateTimeKind` during the transfer, as the SQL type doesn't have anything corresponding to it.